Linking data between Tradingview widgets
I don't know if anyone has experience with tradingview widgets. I currently have a project that demands me to include several of these widgets in a web platform. The widgets work correctly, the problem I am facing now is that the widgets do not link to each other, that is, if I have the widget of a chart and I have another widget with information about some market, when I change the market in the chart, the widget that has the information is not updated.
I could not find any information about this in the Tradingview documentation, so I appreciate any help you can give me!
As you can see, I was looking for a solution in chatgp but still no solution.
To better understand my problem I leave this picture in which you can see 2 different widgets, one of information above and a graph below.
I want that when the market changes in the graph below, the information above is updated.
photo
I leave my code below. Best regards!
HTML
            <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
          <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
          <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js" async>
              {
                "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
                  "width": 550,
                    "locale": "es",
                      "colorTheme": "dark",
                        "isTransparent": true
              }
            </script>
        </div>

      <div class="tradingview-widget-container" id="tradingview_advanced_chart" style="height:100%;width:100%">
        <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget" style="height:calc(100% - 32px);width:100%"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-advanced-chart.js" async>
            {
              "autosize": true,
                "height": "610",
                  "interval": "5",
                    "timezone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
                      "style": "1",
                        "locale": "en",
                          "backgroundColor": "#050505",
                            "hide_side_toolbar": false,
                              "gridColor": "#050505",

                                "allow_symbol_change": true,
                                  "watchlist": [
                                    "FX:GBPUSD",
                                    "FX:USDJPY",
                                    "FX:AUDUSD",
                                    "FX:USDCAD",
                                    "FX:GBPJPY",
                                    "FX:USDCHF",
                                    "FX:GBPAUD",
                                    "FX:EURJPY"
                                  ],
                                    "theme": "dark",
                                      "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
                                        "calendar": false,
                                          "studies": [
                                            "STD;VWAP"
                                          ],
                                            "support_host": "https://www.tradingview.com"
            }
          </script>
          
      </div>

JS
  <script>
function updateAdvancedChart(symbol) {
  const chartIframe = document.querySelector('#tradingview_advanced_chart iframe');
  if (chartIframe) {
    chartIframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
      event: 'set_symbol',
      symbol: symbol
    }, '*');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  if (event.origin !== 'https://screener.tradingview.com') return;

  // Escucha los clicks en el screener
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'click') {
    const clickedSymbol = event.data.symbol;
    updateAdvancedChart(clickedSymbol);
  }
}, false);

